# Solving the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{t+1}{y+1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{t+1}{y+1}, \quad y(1)=2$$
Progress so far: 
$$(y+1) \, dy = (t+1)\,dt$$
$$\int y+1 \ dy = \int (t+1)\,dt$$
$$\frac{y^2}{2} + y = \frac{t^2}{2} + t + C, \quad  \langle y=2, t=1\rangle $$
$$ \frac{5}{2} = C$$

I am not sure how to solve for $y$, Thank you for your help! If you can just give me the name of the technique on how to solve for $y$ or how to setup the integral beforehand so I do not get a $y^2$ on the R.H.S that would also be sufficient.

Also, most of the example online are simple so I am wondering if there are cases, in general, where we integrate and $y$ is not explicitly defined, such as this one? and can they solved through algebraic manipulation? Or is the function just numerically estimated? Thank you for your insight!

Comment: I changed $<y=2, t=1>$ to $\langle y=2, t=1\rangle$.  That is standard. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: And here is an oddity (but really not an oddity): If you write {<}y=2,t=1{>} you see ${<}y=2,t=1{>}$, but if you write <y=2,t=1>, then you see $<y=2,t=1>$ with the makeshift angle brackets at a greater distance from what's between them than they would be if you put curly braces around them.  That's of course to be expected if you understand typesetting, but I hadn't thought of it before. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I can see why this would be the standard; this $\langle y=2, t=1\rangle$ is much prettier than $<y=2,t=1>$. Thanks for informing me! Also, that is counter-intuitive and odd at first sight!

Comment: I believe most people would consider this a solution to the differential equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have $\frac{1}{2}y^2+y - (\frac{1}{2}t^2+t+\tfrac{5}{2}) = 0$, just use the [Quadratic Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) to solve for $y$.

Be sure to select the correct $+$ or $-$ sign.

EDIT: Or as Hurkyl points out below, complete the square as follows:

$$\int (y+1)\,dy = \int(t+1)\,dt$$

$$\frac{1}{2}(y+1)^2 = \frac{1}{2}(t+1)^2+C$$

EDIT2: I just noticed your other question about always being able to solve for $y$.

Consider $\dfrac{dy}{dt} = \dfrac{1}{5y^4+1}$, with initial condition $y(0) = 0$. The solution satisfies $y^5+y = t$.

Let $f(y) = y^5+y$. Since $f$ is strictly increasing, $f^{-1}$ is well defined. Hence, $y = f^{-1}(t)$.

However, we cannot explicitly write $f^{-1}(t)$ in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Or other related methods like completing the square

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Thank you, now I will try this method the next I see this. Thank you @Hurkly!

Answer (score 2):

Rearranging as indicated by JimmyK4542 and Hurkyl gives $(y+1)^2-(t+1)^2=5$.  This is recognizable as a conic section (hyperbola).

Comment: So its solution is a Hyperbola! You have answered my other question too. I guess polynomials with degree 2 and higher are class of functions that can be solutions to ODE.